# Creating PHP Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array in PHP but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. The below does not seem to work. The json is definitely available as when I make a single variable I can access it. The array however does not seem to work.

```
 for ($x=0; $x<=7; $x++){

$forecasetp[] = array();

  $forecastp[x] = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[x]->{'title'};
```

To simplify I am trying to replace the following with a loop

```
$forecastp2 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[1]->{'title'};
    $forecastt2 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[1]->{'fcttext'};

   $forecastp3 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[2]->{'title'};
   $forecastt3 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[2]->{'fcttext'};

    $forecastp4 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[3]->{'title'};
     $forecastt4 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[3]->{'fcttext'};

     $forecastp5 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[4]->{'title'};
          $forecastt5 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[4]->{'fcttext'};

      $forecastp6 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[5]->{'title'};
      $forecastt6 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[5]->{'fcttext'};

       $forecastp7 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[6]->{'title'};
       $forecastt7 = $parsed_json->{'forecast'}->{'txt_forecast'}->{'forecastday'}[6]->{'fcttext'};
```

json being parsed:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "forecast10day": 1
  }
    }
        ,
    "forecast":{
        "txt_forecast": {
        "date":"5:08 PM EDT",
        "forecastday": [
        {
        "period":0,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Sunday",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy. Lows overnight in the upper 50s.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. Low 16C.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":1,
        "icon":"nt_partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Sunday Night",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy skies. Low 59F. Winds WSW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy skies. Low 16C. Winds WSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":2,
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "title":"Monday",
        "fcttext":"Sunny. High 69F. Winds WNW at 10 to 20 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"A mainly sunny sky. High 21C. Winds WNW at 15 to 30 km/h.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":3,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "title":"Monday Night",
        "fcttext":"Clear. Low 46F. Winds NW at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"A mostly clear sky. Low 9C. Winds NW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":4,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Tuesday",
        "fcttext":"Intervals of clouds and sunshine. High 72F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Intervals of clouds and sunshine. High 22C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":5,
        "icon":"nt_partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Tuesday Night",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy skies. Low 51F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy skies. Low 11C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":6,
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "title":"Wednesday",
        "fcttext":"Sunshine and some clouds. High 73F. Winds ENE at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Sunny, along with a few afternoon clouds. High 23C. Winds ENE at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":7,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "title":"Wednesday Night",
        "fcttext":"Mostly clear skies. Low 54F. Winds ENE at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Mostly clear skies. Low 13C. Winds ENE at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":8,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Thursday",
        "fcttext":"Intervals of clouds and sunshine. High 72F. Winds ENE at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy. High 23C. Winds ENE at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"20"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":9,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "title":"Thursday Night",
        "fcttext":"Mainly clear. Low 52F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Mainly clear. Low 12C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"10"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":10,
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "title":"Friday",
        "fcttext":"Sunny skies. High 78F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Some clouds in the morning will give way to mainly sunny skies for the afternoon. High 26C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":11,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "title":"Friday Night",
        "fcttext":"Clear skies. Low 53F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"A mostly clear sky. Low 12C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":12,
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "title":"Saturday",
        "fcttext":"Mainly sunny. High 81F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Sunny skies. High 28C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":13,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "title":"Saturday Night",
        "fcttext":"Clear skies. Low 57F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear skies. Low 14C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":14,
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "title":"Sunday",
        "fcttext":"Sunny. High near 80F. Winds E at 5 to 10 mph.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Mainly sunny. High 27C. Winds E at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"0"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":15,
        "icon":"nt_clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_clear.gif",
        "title":"Sunday Night",
        "fcttext":"A few clouds overnight. Low 58F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Clear to partly cloudy. Low around 15C. Winds SSW at 10 to 15 km/h.",
        "pop":"20"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":16,
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Monday",
        "fcttext":"Mostly cloudy skies early will become partly cloudy later in the day. High 79F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Mostly cloudy skies early, then partly cloudy in the afternoon. High 27C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"20"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":17,
        "icon":"nt_mostlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_mostlycloudy.gif",
        "title":"Monday Night",
        "fcttext":"Partly cloudy skies in the evening, then becoming cloudy overnight. Low 61F. Winds light and variable.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Partly cloudy skies during the evening will give way to cloudy skies overnight. Low 17C. Winds light and variable.",
        "pop":"20"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":18,
        "icon":"chancerain",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/chancerain.gif",
        "title":"Tuesday",
        "fcttext":"Cloudy with occasional light rain. High 73F. Winds NE at 5 to 10 mph. Chance of rain 60%.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Cloudy with occasional light rain. High 23C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h. Chance of rain 60%.",
        "pop":"60"
        }
        ,
        {
        "period":19,
        "icon":"nt_chancerain",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_chancerain.gif",
        "title":"Tuesday Night",
        "fcttext":"Light rain transitioning to a few showers late. Low near 55F. Winds NE at 5 to 10 mph. Chance of rain 60%.",
        "fcttext_metric":"Occasional light rain tapering to a few showers late. Low 14C. Winds NE at 10 to 15 km/h. Chance of rain 60%.",
        "pop":"60"
        }
        ]
        },
        "simpleforecast": {
        "forecastday": [
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1411340400",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 21, 2014",
    "day":21,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":263,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Sun",
    "weekday":"Sunday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":1,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"77",
        "celsius":"24"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"59",
        "celsius":"15"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": null,
        "mm": null
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": null,
        "cm": null
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 3,
        "kph": 5,
        "dir": "",
        "degrees": 0
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 0,
        "kph": 0,
        "dir": "",
        "degrees": 0
        },
        "avehumidity": 73,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1411426800",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 22, 2014",
    "day":22,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":264,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Mon",
    "weekday":"Monday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":2,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"69",
        "celsius":"21"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"46",
        "celsius":"8"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":0,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 20,
        "kph": 32,
        "dir": "WNW",
        "degrees": 300
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 13,
        "kph": 21,
        "dir": "WNW",
        "degrees": 300
        },
        "avehumidity": 55,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1411513200",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 23, 2014",
    "day":23,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":265,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Tue",
    "weekday":"Tuesday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":3,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"72",
        "celsius":"22"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"51",
        "celsius":"11"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":0,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "NW",
        "degrees": 321
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 5,
        "kph": 8,
        "dir": "NW",
        "degrees": 321
        },
        "avehumidity": 52,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1411599600",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 24, 2014",
    "day":24,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":266,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Wed",
    "weekday":"Wednesday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":4,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"73",
        "celsius":"23"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"54",
        "celsius":"12"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":10,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "ENE",
        "degrees": 66
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 8,
        "kph": 13,
        "dir": "ENE",
        "degrees": 66
        },
        "avehumidity": 63,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1411686000",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 25, 2014",
    "day":25,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":267,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Thu",
    "weekday":"Thursday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":5,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"72",
        "celsius":"22"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"52",
        "celsius":"11"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":20,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "ENE",
        "degrees": 63
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 7,
        "kph": 11,
        "dir": "ENE",
        "degrees": 63
        },
        "avehumidity": 73,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1411772400",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 26, 2014",
    "day":26,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":268,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Fri",
    "weekday":"Friday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":6,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"78",
        "celsius":"26"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"53",
        "celsius":"12"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":0,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 5,
        "kph": 8,
        "dir": "NE",
        "degrees": 37
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 4,
        "kph": 6,
        "dir": "NE",
        "degrees": 37
        },
        "avehumidity": 63,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1411858800",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 27, 2014",
    "day":27,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":269,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Sat",
    "weekday":"Saturday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":7,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"81",
        "celsius":"27"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"57",
        "celsius":"14"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":0,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 5,
        "kph": 8,
        "dir": "N",
        "degrees": 11
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 4,
        "kph": 6,
        "dir": "N",
        "degrees": 11
        },
        "avehumidity": 58,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1411945200",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 28, 2014",
    "day":28,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":270,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Sun",
    "weekday":"Sunday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":8,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"80",
        "celsius":"27"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"58",
        "celsius":"14"
        },
        "conditions":"Clear",
        "icon":"clear",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":0,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "E",
        "degrees": 97
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 6,
        "kph": 10,
        "dir": "E",
        "degrees": 97
        },
        "avehumidity": 64,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1412031600",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 29, 2014",
    "day":29,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":271,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Mon",
    "weekday":"Monday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":9,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"79",
        "celsius":"26"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"61",
        "celsius":"16"
        },
        "conditions":"Partly Cloudy",
        "icon":"partlycloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":20,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.00,
        "mm": 0
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 5,
        "kph": 8,
        "dir": "WSW",
        "degrees": 240
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 3,
        "kph": 5,
        "dir": "WSW",
        "degrees": 240
        },
        "avehumidity": 73,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ,
        {"date":{
    "epoch":"1412118000",
    "pretty":"7:00 PM EDT on September 30, 2014",
    "day":30,
    "month":9,
    "year":2014,
    "yday":272,
    "hour":19,
    "min":"00",
    "sec":0,
    "isdst":"1",
    "monthname":"September",
    "monthname_short":"Sep",
    "weekday_short":"Tue",
    "weekday":"Tuesday",
    "ampm":"PM",
    "tz_short":"EDT",
    "tz_long":"America/New_York"
},
        "period":10,
        "high": {
        "fahrenheit":"73",
        "celsius":"23"
        },
        "low": {
        "fahrenheit":"55",
        "celsius":"13"
        },
        "conditions":"Chance of Rain",
        "icon":"chancerain",
        "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/chancerain.gif",
        "skyicon":"",
        "pop":60,
        "qpf_allday": {
        "in": 0.24,
        "mm": 6
        },
        "qpf_day": {
        "in": 0.18,
        "mm": 5
        },
        "qpf_night": {
        "in": 0.06,
        "mm": 2
        },
        "snow_allday": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_day": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "snow_night": {
        "in": 0.0,
        "cm": 0.0
        },
        "maxwind": {
        "mph": 10,
        "kph": 16,
        "dir": "NE",
        "degrees": 50
        },
        "avewind": {
        "mph": 7,
        "kph": 11,
        "dir": "NE",
        "degrees": 50
        },
        "avehumidity": 81,
        "maxhumidity": 0,
        "minhumidity": 0
        }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: posted wrong json first time. Updated with correct json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$forecasetp[] = array();
foreach ($parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday as $day)
{
    $forecastp[] = $day->title;
}
```

This will add the `title` field value as an element to the `$forecastp` array; you can access it as `$forecastp[0]`.

Note:

- If you just want to push elements, without setting them to a specific index, use `$forecastp[]`.
- PHP arrays start counting from `0`.

EDIT: Now I understand what you want to do. Post updated.

Comment: yes I start at 0. Was just trying to make it work. Updated code sample. Still cant get it to work though.

Comment: Use `foreach` instead of `for` on the root JSON object. You don't need to set indices, just use the “push” as posted in my example.

Comment: @user2941841: Ah, I think you want to iterate over the `$parsed_json->forecast->txt_forecast->forecastday` list. Code updated.

Comment: still cant get it to work. Posted the JSON that I am parsing.

Comment: The following code works very well on your posted JSON: http://pastebin.com/WZKjkCEu (basically the same as the answer here, only that it's a complete script.)

Comment: I was able to make this work using your code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Ixg will probably work but only if $json_string is an object.

You could also try

```
$forecastp[] = $parsed_json['forecast10day']['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'][0]->title;
```

The basics are thats ->**_** is for objects and ['____'] is for arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I get this now though: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Could you do print_r($parsed_json) and copy the result into here please?

Comment: json being parsed posted

Comment: Thanks. I adjusted my answer. Looks like you are using Arrays. Just use ['KEY_GOES HERE'] for each item. Try doing one level at a time to test it.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to try and help me but now I get the below (error:Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array i) do I have to initialize the array? New to PHP obviously.